# How to use different methods with generics

Tags: java, generics

```
public class MyGenerics<T extends Number>{
   List<T> = new ArrayList<T>();

   public void addToList(){
     for (ListIterator<T> it; it.hasNext(); ){
         it.next();
         it.add(number());
     }
   }

   public T number(){
     return (T) 5*Math.pi;
   }
}
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell the compiler "I promise, everything that is returned by number() is some object that extends Number and will be cast to type T, whatever it is, because I am casting it.

I am new to generics, so any help is greatly appreciated. I got around this by subclassing the class, but that semi-misses the point of generics.

And please note that the issue isn't really about adding just one value to a list. The issue is the generics logic. (Just to be clear)

Comment: "I promise, everything that is returned by number() is some object that extends Number and will be cast to type T, whatever it is, because I am casting it."   `5*Math.pi` returns a `double`.  Even if you *could* do what you have above, if T is not actually double then the best case scenario would have been `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Not sure why you would use generics for this, or is it just a simplified example?

Answer (score 4):

This problem combines auto-boxing with generics. That ain't going to be pretty.

`5 * Math.PI` is a primitive `double`. To be converted to any type of `Number` object, it needs to be boxed. So, the compiler needs to know the concrete target type for the boxing operation, but it is missing because you are using generics.

If the class is not extended, and `number()` always returns a `double` (or `Double`), don't use use generics; be explicit and use `Double` in place of `T`.

If the class is going to be extended, and the `number()` method is to be overridden, you still know a concrete type. Declare the `List` (which you neglected to name) in the subclass with a matching type parameter.

Comment: Right. I want to preserve the ability to extend the class, in case I want a similar classes that uses Integers instead of Double.

Comment: @Ben B. - What do you want to do with the `Number` objects after they are added to the `List`?

Answer (score 1):

The class definition given by you is telling compiler that you would populate the list with only one particular sub class type of Number.

If you want to mix sub classes, then you should define your method as following

```
public Number number(){
    return 5*Math.PI;
}
```

and remove this entire type  variable as your method cannot guarantee that all children would be double type